# How to add custom command to Cypress / Typescript test framework?

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am trying to add a custom command to my Cypress,Cucumber,Typescript test framework, but am getting the following errors:

I get this error in the `spec.ts` file:
`Property 'seedLocalStorage' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.`

I get this error in the `support/commands.ts` file:
`Argument of type '"seedLocalStorage"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Chainable<any>'`

Below are some of my files.

`index.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command that seeds local storage with the following params:
       * @param key 
       * @param value 
       */
        seedLocalStorage(key: string, value: string): Chainable;
    }
}
```

`support/commands.ts`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('seedLocalStorage', (key, value) => {
    return "some string for now"
})
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "strict": true,
      "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
      "types": ["cypress", "node"]
    },
    "include": [
      "**/*.ts"
    ]
  }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong & how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the type in `index.d.ts` as `Chainable<String>` or `Chainable<string>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's saying you need to return a Chainable wrapper of your value.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('seedLocalStorage', (key, value) => {
  return cy.wrap("some string for now")            // type Chainable<string>
})
```